# ScrollViewer: Zoom to Center of Current page via button

Tags: c#, uwp, zooming, scrollviewer

So I have a program. In this program there is a PDF Reader. For this PDFReader there are Zoom in/out buttons. My problem is the current behaviour of the zoom from the zoom buttons.

For example: When zooming in it zooms towards the top. When zooming out it zooms towards the buttom. (It can even jump pages with it. Going to the top side of page 2 and zoom out makes a jump to the bottom of page 2. Zooming out again jumps to the bottom of page 3. Zooming out again jumpst to page 5/6 (technically bottom of page 5))

I honestly dont know if it is because of the ScrollViewer or because of something else. But I assume it is because of the ScrollViewer.

Does anyone know if I can set the zoom to the center of a current page? Maybe it has something to do with the VerticalOffset (which cant be changed though) or something?

Comment: Can you share some code? Is it the default behaviour of the zoom of some library you are using or is it something you wrote?

Comment: Just in case, this post seems close to your issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c8e7feb-e7c0-4c84-8f36-a72b24d6b510/center-of-scrollviewer-for-using-zoomtofactor?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the [ScrollViewer.ChangeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.changeview) Method to set the scrollviewer's verticalOffset and zoom factor.

```
scrollViewer.ChangeView(0, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset, (scrollViewer.ZoomFactor + 0.1f));
```